# DeprecationWarning: please use dns.resolver.Resolver.resolve()

Tags: python

I am using resolver() as an alternative to socket() as I found that when multiple connections are made to different IPs it ends up stopping working.
Anyway it returns a warning to me that I should use `dns.resolver.Resolver.resolve ()`
When changing it, it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: resolve() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'qname'
```

This is the code:

```
        # my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
        my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver.resolve()
        answers = my_resolver.query(host, "A")
        answer_txt = my_resolver.query(host, "TXT")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

faced the same problem

You should remove `.resolve` from `my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver.resolve()` and replace `my_resolver.query()` with `my_resolver.resolve()`

Example:

```
    my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
    answers = my_resolver.resolve(host, "A")
    answer_txt = my_resolver.resolve(host, "TXT")
```

Comment: I hope #pymongo will fix it soon `.../pymongo/srv_resolver.py:57: DeprecationWarning: please use dns.resolver.resolve() instead
  results = resolver.query(self.__fqdn, 'TXT',`