# AttributeError at / 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_get_qnames_to_try'

Tags: python, html, django, dns

UPDATE: I did some changes now I'm getting this 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_absolute'
.
.
I have been working at a project where I need to print Ip address of a hostname inputed by user in a textfield on html page. I am using Django kinda new at it. I am getting this error no qnames found. Please Help!

Heres Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import dns.resolver


def index(request):
    search = request.POST.get('search')
    # print('search='+search)
    ip_address = dns.resolver.Resolver.resolve(search, "A")
    context = {"ip_address": ip_address}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

UPDATED: views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import dnspython as dns
import dns.resolver


def index(request):
    search = request.POST.get('search')
    # print(search)
    # ip_address = dns.resolver.Resolver.resolve(search, "A")

    ip_address = dns.resolver.Resolver()
    answers = ip_address.resolve(search, "A")

    context = {"ip_address": answers}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block title %} IP Finder {% endblock %}


{% block body %}


<div class="container">
    <br>
    <br>

    <center>
        <h1 style="font-family:'Courier New'">Django NSLookup</h1>
    <br>
    <br>

    <form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="form-group">

            <label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Enter website">

            </label>


        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">
        <p></p>
        <p>Click on the "Choose File" button to upload a file:</p>
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

    </form>
    </center>


    <br>
    <br>


    <p>IP Address is : {{ip_address}}</p>


</div>

{%  endblock %}
```

Traceback of error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
> line 47, in inner
>     response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line
> 181, in _get_response
>     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\vassu\PycharmProjects\IPFinderA\IPApp\views.py", line 20, in
> index
>     ip_address = dns.resolver.Resolver.resolve(search, "A")   File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 1159, in resolve
>     resolution = _Resolution(self, qname, rdtype, rdclass, tcp,   File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 531, in __init__
>     self.qnames_to_try = resolver._get_qnames_to_try(qname, search) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
> '_get_qnames_to_try' [01/Sep/2021 01:27:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 73040
```

UPDATE: Can anyone help me find the cause of error please

[image]

Comment: Also it has worked before.. the same code. I don't know what I am doing wrong here

Comment: you should uncomment the print statement to see what you are sending to ```dns.resolver.Resolver.resolve```.

Comment: @Martin I tried that no console output

Comment: So that is your problem.  It's None.  I would encourage you to not pass None to ```dns.resolver.Resolver.resolve```.  The questions becomes 1) why are you not checking the input from the form and 2) why is it None?

Comment: @Martin Didt that ....TypeError at /
resolve() missing 1 required positional argument: 'qname'

Comment: Have a look here and adjust your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64712172/deprecationwarning-please-use-dns-resolver-resolver-resolve

Comment: @Martin Did still the same...Exception Value: 
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_absolute'
Exception Location: C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py, line 1006, in _get_qnames_to_try

Comment: UPDATE: I did some changes now I'm getting this 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_absolute'

Comment: `search = request.POST.get('search')` and you never check it is both non empty and conforming to what you expect? What a nice way to do an injection and abuse your code remotely...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Could you please explain a lil more I'm new to this

Comment: Please take the time to read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/

Comment: Can you point out to a perticular problem in index.html?

Comment: I have update the question with details of variables. Please Help

Comment: you keep passing None as search.  I get the same error, 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_absolute', when I pass None too: ```ip_address = dns.resolver.Resolver()``` followed by ```dns.resolver.resolve(None, 'A').rrset[0].to_text()```.  Your variables show 'search' as being None.  This is your issue.  You are not reading the value from the form correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace:

```
ip_address = dns.resolver.Resolver.resolve(search, "A")
```

by:

```
try:
    ip_address = dns.resolver.resolve(search, 'A').rrset[0].to_text()
except dns.resolver.NoAnswer:
    ip_address = 'No answer'
```

Comment: Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_absolute'
Exception Location: C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py, line 1033, in _get_qnames_to_try

Comment: `search` variable is None... If you don't check your input...

Comment: Could you explain a lil more please