# Cant get reponse request.POST.get in views.py index function

Tags: python, html, django, dns

I am trying to create a webapp which diplays IP Address of a hostname which should be input from user in textField. But I keep getting this error.I cant see to get reponse in url. I am new to this please help.

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import dnspython as dns
import dns.resolver


def index(request):
    search = request.POST.get('search')
    # print(search)
    ip_address = dns.resolver.Resolver.resolve(search, "A")

    # ip_address = dns.resolver.Resolver()
    # answers = ip_address.resolve(search, "A").rrset[0].to_text()

    # try:
    #     ip_address = dns.resolver.resolve(search, 'A').rrset[0].to_text()
    # except dns.resolver.NoAnswer:
    #     ip_address = 'No answer'



    context = {"ip_address": ip_address}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

This is the html Please have a look and check.
Thanks in advance.

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block title %} IP Finder {% endblock %}


{% block body %}


<div class="container">
    <br>
    <br>

    <center>
        <h1 style="font-family:'Courier New'">Django NSLookup</h1>
    <br>
    <br>

    <form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="form-group">

            <label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Enter website">

            </label>


        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">
        <p></p>
        <p>Click on the "Choose File" button to upload a file:</p>
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

    </form>
    </center>


    <br>
    <br>


    <p>IP Address is : {{ip_address}}</p>


</div>

{%  endblock %}
```

[image]

Traceback:

> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
> > line 47, in inner
> > response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line
> > 181, in _get_response
> > response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\vassu\PycharmProjects\IPFinderA\IPApp\views.py", line 22, in
> > index
> > ip_address = dns.resolver.Resolver.resolve(search, "A")   File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 1186, in resolve
> > resolution = _Resolution(self, qname, rdtype, rdclass, tcp,   File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 552, in **init**
> > self.qnames_to_try = resolver._get_qnames_to_try(qname, search) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
> > '_get_qnames_to_try' [01/Sep/2021 04:07:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 73961

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError at / 'NoneType' object has no attribute '\_get\_qnames\_to\_try'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69004777/attributeerror-at-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-get-qnames-to-try)

Comment: This too was my question. Please look into that as well, please.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69004777/attributeerror-at-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-get-qnames-to-try

Comment: I need a solution. Its very important!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
dns.resolver.Resolver.resolve()
```

use:

```
dns.resolver.Resolver.query()
```

Comment: I hope you meant dns.resolver.query() but it still shows the same error. I am getting value in self : dns.resolver.Resolver.query() object at 0x00000194B1C95DF0> instead of variable search